# Multi-platform (Chrome, IE, Firefox)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex, html5-canvas, three.js

I don't undestand why this script doesn't work in IE, while it works in Firefox and Chrome. When I try to use this script in IE, I get this message "ACTIVEX stop script".

Please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Getting Started with Three.js</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/Three.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( 800, 600 );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      35,       // Field of view
      800 / 600,    // Aspect ratio
      0.1,      // Near plane
      10000       // Far plane
    );
    camera.position.set( 15, 10, 10 );
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );
    scene.add( camera );
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(
      new THREE.CubeGeometry( 5, 5, 5 ),
      new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xFF0000 } )
    );
    scene.add( cube );
    var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xFFFF00 );
    light.position.set( 10, 0, 10 );
    scene.add( light );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
  };
  </script>
</head>
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Three.js WebGLRenderer doesn't work in IE (no WebGL support)

try

```
var renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer()
```

instead

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the very simple solution above you can utilize alteredq and mrdoob's great **[Detector.js script](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/Detector.js)** that is included with the **[examples for three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/examples/js)**. If you use code like below you can use the WebGLRenderer as default and use canvas only if WebGL is not available. You can also use a flag like webglEnabled in order to set other options depending on your renderer later in your code.

```
var webglEnabled = false;
var webglReq = false;

if (Detector.webgl) {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(
            {
                antialias: true,
                preserveDrawingBuffer: true
            });  // allow screenshot 

    webglEnabled = true; // set flag 
}
else if (webglReq) { Detector.addGetWebGLMessage(); return false; } 
else {
    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
}
renderer.setClearColorHex(0x000000, 1);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
```

Comment: Agreed. Its always worth providing WebGL Renderer to your visitors who can use it. No need to make everyone suffer, just because some people use IE ;-)

Comment: Yeah, really the only reason I would say not to use something like this would be because of added complexity of dealing with the possibilities of two different sets of rendering capabilities, which may be a little much depending on the project.